# Determine my customer's iOS Versions

Tags: iphone, ios, app-store-connect

I am trying to decide if I should keep support for iOS 4.x in the next build of my app or drop it an only support iOS 5 & 6 going forward.  Does Apple report back to the developer the iOS version for each app sold so I can get an idea of the demand for my app from older devices?  I have scoured iTunesConnect but I do not see it there.

I would rather not maintain the support going back that far, but if the user community and demand it there, it may make financial sense to do so.

Thanks!

Comment: I'd say drop iOS 4. Luckily iOS users are pretty quick to adopt new OS's so you won't really lose a lot of potential customers

Comment: THat is my feeling too, but it would be helpful to base the decision on something more measurable than that.  :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Apple doesn't report this back to you via iTunes connect. You need to integrate this into your app via third parties like google analytics, flurry, or any other platform.

It's also very easy to report the version with `[[UIDevice currentDevice] systemVersion]` if you can roll your own analytics system.

Answer (score 0):

As Jessedc mentioned you can use `[[UIDevice currentDevice] systemVersion]`, however, you don't have to roll your own analytics system. Several of the analytics platforms out there (Google's analytics, Flurry, etc) allow you to **technically** submit this information via custom events but be aware the user agreements might prohibit you from doing it.

Note that you if want accurate statistics, an I'm assuming you do, you need to carefully determine when to submit or resubmit the information to your analytics platform, otherwise, you can end with **very** inaccurate data.